# Scala: constructor arguments involving inner types of bounded types

Tags: scala

In scala 2.9.0.RC3, I defined a trait for parsers and a concrete example of a parser:

```
trait Parser {
  type Result
  def parse(s: String): Result
}

class IdParser extends Parser {
  case class Result(s: String)
  def parse(s: String) = new Result(s)
}
```

Now I'd like to be able to compare parsed values:

```
class Comparator[P <: Parser](p: P) {
  def compare(s1: String, s2: String) = p.parse(s1) == p.parse(s2)
}
```

This works fine, I can do:

```
println(new Comparator(new IdParser).compare("a", "b"))
```

And it produces *false*, as expected. Unfortunately, it gets downhill from here. To allow for fancier comparison, I define:

```
class CustomisableComparator[P <: Parser](p: P, 
      cmp: (P#Result, P#Result) => Boolean = (r1: P#Result, r2: P#Result) => r1 == r2) {
  def compare(s1: String, s2: String) = cmp(p.parse(s1), p.parse(s2))
}
```

And try to invoke it as before:

```
println(new CustomisableComparator(new IdParser).compare("a", "b"))
```

But then:

```
error: type mismatch;
 found   : (this.Parser#Result, this.Parser#Result) => Boolean
 required: (this.IdParser#Result, this.IdParser#Result) => Boolean
Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
println(new CustomisableComparator(new IdParser).compare("a", "b"))
        ^
```

Oh, well, I'd expect the type variable `P` in `CustomisableComparator` to be bound to `IdParser`, so I'm not quite sure why scala thinks it's `Parser` in the default value. Let's forget about the default then and provide the value explicitly:

```
println(new CustomisableComparator(new IdParser, (r1: IdParser#Result, r2: IdParser#Result) => r1 == r2).compare("a", "b"))
```

```
error: type mismatch;
 found   : (this.IdParser#Result, this.IdParser#Result) => Boolean
 required: (?#Result, ?#Result) => Boolean

println(new CustomisableComparator(new IdParser, (r1: IdParser#Result, r2: IdParser#Result) => r1 == r2).compare("a", "b"))
                                                                                            ^
```

This is well confusing. If I don't provide a value, the compiler expects `(this.IdParser#Result, this.IdParser#Result) => Boolean`; once I do provide a value of this type, it expects `(?#Result, ?#Result) => Boolean`. Can anyone explain what is going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're just asking too much of type inference.  You seem to think it's going to backtrack for you, and it isn't.

Both your examples compile if you supply the type:

```
println(new CustomisableComparator[Parser](new IdParser).compare("a", "b"))
println(new CustomisableComparator[IdParser](new IdParser, (r1: IdParser#Result, r2: IdParser#Result) => r1 == r2).compare("a", "b"))
```

Or, you will get better type inference in these situations (it goes from left to right) if you use additional parameter lists in strategic locations.

```
class CustomisableComparator2[P <: Parser](p: P)(cmp: (P#Result, P#Result) => Boolean = ((x: P#Result, y: P#Result) => x == y)) {
  def compare(s1: String, s2: String) = cmp(p.parse(s1), p.parse(s2))
}
// type parameter successfully inferred
println(new CustomisableComparator2(new IdParser)((r1: IdParser#Result, r2: IdParser#Result) => r1 == r2).compare("a", "b"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I'm still confused as to why the "required" type is different when using the default and explicit args. The first "required" suggests that the compiler was able to infer the type of the function correctly. It suddenly loses this ability in the second case.

My expectations as to what the inferencer should be able to do were set by a brief exposure to Haskell. It seems to always be able to infer at least as much as I can, and often more. In this case the inference seemed obvious to me so I was hoping scalac would figure it out as well.